# Issue with parsing JSON data

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to convert a string into a json object and am unsure why this is not working. When I nslog the output I am told that urldata is not valid for json serialization however when looking at the string it looks to me like valid json. I have also tried encoding it to an utf8 however it still won't serialize. Am I missing something here? - Note unnecessary code omitted from post.

Get request

```
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSDictionary alloc];
```

Parsing

```
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:urlData] ) {
    NSLog(@"is valid");
    tempDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData kniloptions error:&error];
}

NSLog(@"is not valid");
```

Definition:
isValidJSONObject:
Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be converted to JSON data.

Comment: IsValidJsonObject sounds like the wrong method. Sounds like it is checking the object before converting it to data. You want it the other way round.

Comment: @Fogmeister: You're probably right.  Seems to me, though, that in that case `isValidJSONObject` should always return true.  (What keeps an NSString from being JSON-serializable?)

Comment: urlData is an NSData object. You cannot encode an NSData object into JSON data. He is checking for encoding the object. He needs to check for decoding the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are already mentioning in your question, [isValidJSONObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/isValidJSONObject%3a)

> returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be
>   converted **to** JSON data

In your case, you don't want to create JSON data, but instead create a dictionary out of JSON data. :

```
tempDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                             error:&error];

if (!tempDict) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
}
```